# Falcon fairing half - between separation and parachutes deployment

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, attitude, aerodynamics, fairings

**How does Falcon fairing half behaves in atmosphere before parachutes deployment?**

What is its free fall attitude in atmosphere?

- Is the fairing's attitude stable (with some wobbling, but without rotation)?
- Or is it in stable rotation?
- Or unstable rotation (chaotic changes of attitude)?

*I guess the last is unlikely because it would complicate the use of thrusters and parachutes.*

**What is the height where the parachutes deployed? What is the speed?**

P.S.

If no solid sources available - educated guesses are welcome

Comment: May be a  spring-loaded pilot chute is used to deploy the main parachutes. Such a pilot chute may help if the free fall attitude in atmosphere of the fairing half is unfavorable.